Unity shader graph show through walls
How to make a shader graph shader display through walls while keeping the existing texture in unity. I also only want to  use shader graph only nothing else.
Example: https://hyunkell.com/blogfiles/Overlay/DepthTest.jpg
In the example I would want something like the character on the far right. It has a shader and displays through the wall.

When one of your questions gets closed for not including enough detail, please edit the original question instead of posting a new one about the same topic. Repeatedly posting new questions instead of re-opening old ones can make our automated systems flag the post as an attempt to evade moderation.

As with your previous question, I don't see much evidence here that you've attempted to research this yourself before asking here. Searching "unity outline through wall" turns up plenty of past discussion of how to implement such an effect, and even ready-made assets that do this, which you can just download. Where specifically have you run into trouble leveraging this wealth of existing support?

We also have a related question with an accepted answer on render occluded pixels with a shader in Unity.

Yes my bad Gregory I did not mean to harm no one. I have looked at many tutorials and even the ones u sent but the tutorials are for the old shaders not the new shader graphs. And some of them say you need 2 cameras but I only want to use a shader graph nothing else. And mr Pikalek that tutorial i think is for the old shader with the code the new shader graph is no coding thanks.
